# Unrecognized attribute 'controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion'

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

We are replacing our win2k3 server (iis6) with a win2012 (iis8) and when we move the asp.net apps over from the old server, configure them as applications and point them to the 2.0 framework, then attempt to run we get this:

```
Unrecognized attribute 'controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion'

Line 2:  <configuration>
Line 3:      <system.web>
Line 4:          <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.5" />
Line 5:      </system.web>
Line 6:  </configuration>

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.6407; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.6406
```

I have been trying things all day and the strange thing is that the source file points the IIS's root web.config even though the application has it's own with the  tag.

Please note this is a legacy app that cannot be updated to asp.net 4+.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found something that worked for me finally.  I did the manual conversion of the web.config in this link:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Then I upgraded the app pool to 4.5 (4 was not an option for me but it might be for you).